# Working on a Triangle calculator but DMOJ won't accept the code

Tags: java, calculator

[What DMOJ says about my code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YV4Qp.png)

```
 import java.io.*;
    public class TriangleCalculator
    {
        public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
        {

            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (System.in);

            int angle1, angle2, angle3;
            String sentinel;

            System.out.print ("Would you like to use the calculator? (Y/N): ");
            sentinel = input.readLine ();
            System.out.println ("");

            while (!sentinel.equalsIgnoreCase ("n"))
            {
                System.out.print ("Please enter the measurement for the first angle: ");
                angle1 = Integer.parseInt (input.readLine ());

                System.out.println ("");

                System.out.print ("Please enter the measurement for the second angle: ");
                angle2 = Integer.parseInt (input.readLine ());

                System.out.println ("");

                System.out.print ("Please enter the measurement for the third angle: ");
                angle3 = Integer.parseInt (input.readLine ());

                System.out.println ("");

                if (angle1 + angle2 + angle3 != 180 | angle1 <= 0 | angle2 <= 0 | angle3 <= 0)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Error");
                    System.out.println ("");
                }
                else if ((angle1 == angle2 && angle1 != angle3) | (angle1 == angle3 && angle1 != angle2) | (angle2 == angle3 && angle2 != angle1) | (angle3 == angle1 && angle3 != angle2))
                {
                    System.out.println ("Isoceles");
                    System.out.println ("");
                }
                else if (angle1 != angle2 && angle1 != angle3 && angle2 != angle3)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Scalene");
                    System.out.println ("");
                }
                else if (angle1==angle2 &&angle1==angle3&&angle2==angle3)
                {
                    System.out.println ("Equilateral");
                    System.out.println ("");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println ("I wrote this just for memes");
                }
                System.out.print ("Would you like to use the calculator again? (Y/N): ");
                sentinel = input.readLine ();
                System.out.println ("");
            }
            System.out.println ("Alrighty, bye");

        }
    }
```

I am having a bit of trouble with this calculator that I have made. It is very simple, but the problem is, DMOJ says that there is something wrong. In 2 out of 7 occasions, my calculator's answer is wrong.

I have not been able to find similar questions online.

Comment: Where's your test cases? Where's any indication at all that you did anything to verify this code before posting here? You are aware that the purpose of online tests is to hone your programming and debugging skills, rather than you ability to ask other people for help. yes?

Comment: I have tested my code multiple times with different occasions, but DMOJ still considers it incorrect.

Comment: Also, I am not very exprienced at coding, or at using stackoverflow

Comment: Would you reproduce in your question the list of things that DMOJ says is wrong with it?

Comment: I added a picture to the post showing what DMOJ says about my code.

Comment: What is your input on those test cases and what is the expected output?

Comment: DMOJ does not tell you the inputs, and it doesn not tell the expected outputs. However, they do show the incorrect output.

Comment: If you wanna try the challenge on your own... go to DMOJ and do CCC '14 J1 Triangle Times on page 6 or 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, y'all. I found the answer, it was the spelling of isosceles. I had written isoceles. Thanks for your good advice, though, I'll take them into consideration. I got it all figured out.